# What is the locations of the registry files in Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-registry

Looking for the physical files the Windows 2008 R2 server registry. Does anyone know their location and names?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HKLM\System - %windir%\system32\config\SYSTEM
HKLM\Software - %windir%\system32\config\SOFTWARE
HKLM\Security - %windir%\system32\config\SECURITY
HKLM\Sam - %windir%\system32\config\SAM
HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT - %windir%\system32\config\Default
HKEY_USERS\[SID] - %userprofile%\Ntuser.dat
HKCU\[SID]\Software\Classes - %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Usrclass.dat